# How do define the account addresses when running truffle test?

Tags: truffle, addresses, unittesting

By default truffle uses **testrpc** / **truffle develop** which has a list of predefined addresses:

```
Truffle Develop started at http://localhost:9545/

Accounts:
(0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
(1) 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
(2) 0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef
(3) 0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544
(4) 0x0d1d4e623d10f9fba5db95830f7d3839406c6af2
(5) 0x2932b7a2355d6fecc4b5c0b6bd44cc31df247a2e
(6) 0x2191ef87e392377ec08e7c08eb105ef5448eced5
(7) 0x0f4f2ac550a1b4e2280d04c21cea7ebd822934b5
(8) 0x6330a553fc93768f612722bb8c2ec78ac90b3bbc
(9) 0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de
```

How can I overwrite or add addresses ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cli option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-testrpc#command-line) `--account='***'`

> Specify `--account=...`  any number of times passing arbitrary private
>   keys and their associated balances to generate initial addresses:

Example:

```
testrpc -l 6000000 --account=\"0xb70f3dfa1a8b7d3f1e4e64f1bfb6f765acb87e89f455eb19240a8005415c984e,1000000000000000000000\" --unlock \"0x32e0eee34b6a76ffed8d17ed7d365f779f3da3e3\"
```

Comment: Should I run this everytime? And how to include this in truffle test?

Comment: I use the `package.json`  scripts, define once and run by `npm`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to get this working. Can you post a complete package.json file?

Comment: Here is an example of my package.json https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/51474dff2c1b3114d2fef0b5e5b13f28

Comment: I see. However I don't want to install testrpc globally, but just for my project. Is this possible? And what would be the command ?

Comment: I didn't install testrpc globally, only for one project. I omit dependencies for brevity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70809/discussion-between-stef-heyenrath-and-).